# ruby sum values in array by keys

Tags: ruby, arrays, sum

How to sum

```
[["a", 1], ["b", 2], ["c", 3], ["a", 20], ["b", 12], ["c", 5]]
```

into

```
[["a", 21], ["b", 14], ["c", 8]]
```

I don't understand how to combine array map by keys with inject(&:+) by value in such keys

Comment: You'll see that several of the solutions have `inject(:+)` (aka `reduce`), rather than `inject(&:+)`; that is, `+` is not being converted to a proc.  You'll only see that for [Enumerable#inject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject), because it has the nifty feature that if you pass it a symbol, "then each element in the collection will be passed to the named method of memo. ...the result becomes the new value for memo. At the end of the iteration, the final value of memo is the return value for the method" (from the docs).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
.group_by(&:first).map { |k, v| [k, v.map(&:last).inject(:+)] }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x = [["a", 1], ["b", 2], ["c", 3], ["a", 20], ["b", 12], ["c", 5]]
y = Hash.new(0)
x.each {|a| y[a[0]] += a[1]}
y.to_a

=> [["a", 21], ["b", 14], ["c", 8]]
```

Answer (score 2):

My functional solution

```
array = [["a", 1], ["b", 2], ["c", 3], ["a", 20], ["b", 12], ["c", 5]]

array.group_by do |a|
  a.first
end.map do |k, v|
  [k, v.reduce(0) { |acc, (l, r)| acc + r }]
end
# => [["a", 21], ["b", 14], ["c", 8]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = [["a", 1], ["b", 2], ["c", 3], ["a", 20], ["b", 12], ["c", 5]]

arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |x,hsh| hsh[x[0]] += x[1] }.to_a
# => [["a", 21], ["b", 14], ["c", 8]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = [["a", 1], ["b", 2], ["c", 3], ["a", 20], ["b", 12], ["c", 5]]

arr.group_by(&:first).map { |k,v| [k,v.transpose.last.reduce(:+)]}     
  #=> [["a", 21], ["b", 14], ["c", 8]]
```